# Generate html in for each with closing tag every 4 loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to generate the following html :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
</div>
```

So I tried the following :

```js
var response = '[{"id":7},{"id":10},{"id":15},{"id":11},{"id":14},{"id":9},{"id":8},{"id":12},{"id":1}]'
var json = $.parseJSON(response);
var add_html = "";
$(json).each(function (i, val) {
    if (i % 4 == 0){
        add_html += "<div class='row'>";
    }
    add_html = add_html + "<div class='col-md-3'></div>";
    if (i % 4 == 0){
        add_html = add_html + "</div>";
    }
});
/*
if (i % 4 != 1){
    add_html = add_html + "</div>";
}
*/
console.log(add_html)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

But doesn't output the desired result

Comment: What *is* the output of add_html? Have you checked if the loop runs at all?

Comment: use  array_chunks  functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like below. And check changes with comment.

There are two changes in your code.

1. You need to open your `row` div with `i%4 == 0` and close it with `i%4 == 3`.
2. Once `each` loop complete you should check if `(json.length - 1) % 4 != 3` then need to add `</div>`

```js
var response = '[{"id":7},{"id":10},{"id":15},{"id":11},{"id":14},{"id":9},{"id":8},{"id":12},{"id":1}]'
var json = $.parseJSON(response);

var add_html = "";
$(json).each(function(i, val) {
  if (i % 4 == 0) {
    add_html += "<div class='row'>";
  }
  add_html = add_html + "<div class='col-md-3'></div>";
  // Change 1 - Update condition here to compare with 3
  if (i % 4 == 3) {
    add_html += "</div>";    
  }
});

// Change 2 - Add additional condition
if ((json.length - 1) % 4 != 3) {
  add_html += "</div>";
}

console.log(add_html)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

**Old version**

1. Initialize `add_html` with opening row div.
2. When `i % 4 == 3` which means it is forth index add closing div and open a new one.
3. Once `each` loop completes then add closing div.

Note - This has one bug. It will add extra `<div class='row'></div>` when json array is of `json.length % 4 == 0` .

```js
var response = '[{"id":7},{"id":10},{"id":15},{"id":11},{"id":14},{"id":9},{"id":8},{"id":12},{"id":1}]'
var json = $.parseJSON(response);

// Initialize your html with opening row div
var add_html = "<div class='row'>";
$(json).each(function(i, val) {
  add_html = add_html + "<div class='col-md-3'></div>";
  if (i % 4 == 3) { // <- Update condition here to compare with 3
    // Close current row div and open new one
    add_html += "</div>";
    add_html += "<div class='row'>";
  }
});

// End your html with closing row div
add_html = add_html + "</div>";

console.log(add_html)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

To achieve your goal you could batch the original array in to groups of 4 and then use `map()` to iterate through that and create the HTML you require:

```js
var json = $.parseJSON('[{"id":7},{"id":10},{"id":15},{"id":11},{"id":14},{"id":9},{"id":8},{"id":12},{"id":1}]');

let perChunk = 4;
json = json.reduce((all, one, i) => {
  const ch = Math.floor(i / perChunk);
  all[ch] = [].concat((all[ch] || []), one);
  return all
}, [])

let html = json.map(chunk => `<div class="row">${chunk.map(item => `<div class="col-md-3"></div>`).join('')}</div>`).join('');
console.log(html);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You're right - I updated it for you with a better approach

Answer (score 0):

```
        var response = '[{"id":7},{"id":10},{"id":15},{"id":11},{"id":14},{"id":9},{"id":8},{"id":12},{"id":1}]'
        var json = JSON.parse(response);
        const add_html = json.map(() => '<div class="col-md-3"></div>').reduce((pre, cur) => {
            const arr = pre[pre.length - 1];
            if (arr.length >= 4) {
                pre.push([cur])
            } else {
                arr.push(cur);
            }
            return pre;
        }, [[]]).map(item => `<div class="row">${item.join('')}</div>`).join('')
```